# Is the proof I made correct?

Tags: number-theory

For odd prime p $$x^4\equiv-1\pmod p\:\text{ is solvable, then }\:p\equiv1\,(mod\,8)$$

I proved in this way. 
Let $r$ be primitive root of $p$. Then,

$$x^4\equiv-1\pmod p\:\text{is solvable}\Leftrightarrow\;4\text{ind}_rx\equiv\text{ind}_r(-1)\pmod{p-1}\:\text{is solvable}$$

$$r^{p-1}-1=(r^\frac{p-1}{2}-1)(r^\frac{p-1}{2}+1)\equiv0\pmod p$$
If $\;r^\frac{p-1}{2}\equiv1\pmod p$, contradiction. Therefore
$r^\frac{p-1}{2}\equiv-1\pmod p\;$

So, $4\text{ind}_rx\equiv\text{ind}_p(-1)\equiv\dfrac{p-1}{2}\pmod {p-1}$.
Let $d=\text{gcd}(4,{p-1})$, then $d$ is either $2$ or $4$.

If $d=2$, then, $\dfrac{p-1}{2}=\dfrac{p-1}{d}$ so, $d\nmid\dfrac{p-1}{2}$ contradiction. So $d=4$, therefore $4\mid \dfrac{p-1}{2}$ so, $p\equiv1 \pmod 8$.

Comment: I think overusing TeX formulas is not a good idea, though it is absolutely better than not using TeX scripts.  Anyway, could you explain why $r^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 0 \pmod {p}$ leads to a contradiction?

Comment: r^{(p-1)/2} ≡ 1 (mod p). Not r^{(p-1)/2} ≡ 0 (mod p).  Because r is primitve root of p, r^(p-1) ≡ 1 (mod p). And consider x^2 -1 ≡ 0 (mod p). There's exactly 2 solutions.

Comment: Oh, sorry, there is a typo. But I still do not understand why $r^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 1\pmod {p}$ implies a contradiction...

Comment: r is primitive root of p, so, the order of r modulo p is p-1. If r^{(p-1)/2}  ≡  1 (mod p), the order of r is smaller than p-1. This contradicts to our chose of r as a primitive root of p.

Comment: I got it. Your proof looks correct.